# Query for all nested XML types in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a string that consists of XML lines that looks like this:

```xml
<FIXML>
  <TrdCaptRpt TrdTyp = "0" TrdSubTyp = "7" />
</FIXML>

<FIXML>
  <TrdCaptRptAck TrdTyp = "0" TrdSubTyp = "7" />
</FIXML>

<FIXML>
  <TrdCaptRptAck TrdTyp = "1" />
</FIXML>
```

I have some specialized LINQ queries:

```
var q =
    from el in clearingMessagesDoc.Elements("ClearingMessages")
                                  .Elements("FIXML")
                                  .Elements("TrdCaptRpt")
                                  .Where(f => f.Attribute("TrdTyp") != null)
    select el.Attribute("TrdTyp");

var t =
    from el in q
    let trdtyp = el.Value
    group trdtyp by trdtyp.Trim() into g
    orderby g.Key descending
    select new { 
        TrdType = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count() 
    };

t.Dump("TrdCaptRpt");

q = from el in learingMessagesDoc.Elements("ClearingMessages")
                                 .Elements("FIXML")
                                 .Elements("TrdCaptRpt")
                                 .Where(f => f.Attribute("TrdSubTyp") != null)
    select el.Attribute("TrdSubTyp");

var t1 =
    from el in q
    let trdSubtyp = el.Value
    group trdSubtyp by trdSubtyp.Trim() into g
    orderby g.Key descending
    select new { 
        TrdSubTyp = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count() 
    };
```

That works but it hard-codes the report types (`TrdCaptRpt`, `TrdCaptRptAck`, etc.) into the queries. How do I modify the queries so that no matter what report types may be added in the future, I can run a generalized query that will tell me the count of each `TrdTyp` and `TradSubType` corresponding to whether it is of `TrdCaptRpt`, `TrdCaptRptAck` and so on?

So the question is about how to do report on nested attributes, if they exist, indexed by report type.

I am hoping to get something like this for the XML example given:

```
TrdCaptRpt
    TrdTyp = "0" : 1
    TrdSubTyp = "7" : 1

TrdCaptRptAck 
    TrdTyp = "0" : 1
    TrdTyp = "1" : 1
    TrdSubTyp = "7" : 1
```

If there were any other attributes, it would give the report on the count of those too.

--

[Response to Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498359/query-for-all-nested-xml-types-in-linq/6501388#6501388): Thanks that is very very close. I realized that I have not given enough information. The XML file is quite a bit more complicated (This is just a very small part of what it looks like for brevity sake).

```
<FIXML>
 <TrdCaptRpt TrdTyp = "0" TrdSubTyp = "7">
 <Hdr Snt="2011-05-18T12:26:09-05:00" />
  <RptSide Side="2">
    <Pty ID="GS" R="21"></Pty>
  </RptSide >
 </TrdCaptRpt>
</FIXML>
```

In other words, there could be lots of nested stuff to each level. Is there a general way to get at all of these, counting how often each attribute occurs, as per the example you gave indexed by report type?

When I run your queryon an XML that looks sort of like this, it doesn't go below TrdCaptRpt.

Thanks.

Comment: I've removed the commented out code, it was just too much noise.  So if I'm understanding your question correctly, you just want to count how many attributes appear in the elements under the `FIXML` element for each element name?

Comment: p.s., Just a tip, if you want to get the attention of someone who has provided an answer, leave a comment on the answer.  I do not receive any notification of any updates you make on your post or any other answers.  I normally would have noticed your update but I ran in to some connection problems so I wasn't able to check SO as frequently as I usually do.  I'll address your update with an update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood what you wanted in your question, I believe this is what you want:

```
var counts = clearingMessagesDoc
    .Elements("ClearingMessages")
    .Elements("FIXML")
    .Elements()
    .GroupBy(e => e.Name.ToString())
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.SelectMany(e => e.Attributes())
              .GroupBy(attr => new { Name = attr.Name.ToString(), Value = attr.Value.Trim() })
              .OrderBy(attrg => attrg.Key.Name)
              .ThenBy(attrg => attrg.Key.Value)
              .ToDictionary(
                  attrg => String.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", attrg.Key.Name, attrg.Key.Value),
                  attrg => attrg.Count()));
```

It yields the results:

```
Element: TrdCaptRpt
  TrdSubTyp="7": 1
  TrdTyp="0": 1
```

This will create a dictionary of dictionaries of the counts of your attribute/value pairs per element type.  It counts *all* attributes for *all* elements however.  I couldn't tell which elements or attributes you wanted to count.

---

If you want to go further down the element hierarchy, change the last `Elements()` call to `Descendants()` and that will include all the nested elements and their attribute counts.

```
var counts = clearingMessagesDoc
    .Elements("ClearingMessages")
    .Elements("FIXML")
    .Descendants() // checks ALL elements in the hierarchy
    .GroupBy(e => e.Name.ToString())
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.SelectMany(e => e.Attributes())
              .GroupBy(attr => new { Name = attr.Name.ToString(), Value = attr.Value.Trim() })
              .OrderBy(attrg => attrg.Key.Name)
              .ThenBy(attrg => attrg.Key.Value)
              .ToDictionary(
                  attrg => String.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", attrg.Key.Name, attrg.Key.Value),
                  attrg => attrg.Count()));
```

It yields the following results:

```
Element: TrdCaptRpt
  TrdSubTyp="7": 1
  TrdTyp="0": 1
Element: Hdr
  Snt="2011-05-18T12:26:09-05:00": 1
Element: RptSide
  Side="2": 1
Element: Pty
  ID="GS": 1
  R="21": 1
```